# Adding vertical stretch at a table row?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

I have a `longtable` that is used to produce checklist forms. The basic layout is shown below,
  [image] [image]

The second page (if there is one - some forms are quite short) would be  better if it had the bottom row of the table extend vertically to meet the top of the `signature block` below - which is a separate `tabular`. Is there a way to add vertical stretch like a `\vfill` effect in a table row? Any other suggestions.

A trimmed working minimal version of the code is listed below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{amssymb}[2002/01/22] %% for the Box

%% Set up counters for the check items
%% The counters are defined globally in a header
%% so we only step the counters here
%%
%% qnumber is the question counter

\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}


%% new counter for headings in forms
%% 
\newcounter{hcounter}
\setcounter{hcounter}{0}


%% We define the yesno macro that is used
%% by the questions to print the Yes No and 
%% tick boxes
\newcommand{\yesno}{\textsf{Yes}\hskip9pt\textsf{No} {\Large ~$\Box$}~~~~{\Large $\Box$}}

%% we now define the questions
%% since they are not all questions a better term
%% would be added on the next revision
%
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
\stepcounter{qnumber}%
\hfill\thehcounter.\theqnumber\hfill\hfill &\textsf{#1} &{\small\yesno}&    {\small\yesno}&{\small\yesno}\\ \hline%
}

%% we now define the question headings
%% Every time a heading is called
%% The hcounter is incremented and the qnumber set to 1

\newcommand{\heading}[1]{%
\stepcounter{hcounter}%  
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}%
\hfill\textbf{\thehcounter.0}\hfill\hfill&\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\bf\textsf{#1}}\\ \hline %
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{7mm}|p{8.61cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.55cm}|}
\heading{Controls}
  \question{Control valves/actuators properly installed.}
  \question{Control valves/actuators operable.}
  \question{BMS signals operable.}
  \question{Control valves/actuators properly installed.}
  \question{Vibration isolation devices installed?}
\heading{Other} 
  \question{Access doors are operable and sealed? } 
  \question{Casing undamaged?}
  \question{Insulation undamaged?}
  \question{Condensate drainage is unobstructed?}
%% the end portion of the environment
%% add the remarks columns and close the longtable
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\bf {\textsf{DISCREPANCIES}}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{}\\
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{}\\
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{}\\
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{}\\
\hline%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: save the coordinates of the first row and compare the y value of the last row with the one of the first row. Then you can insert an invisible vertical rule.

Comment: @Herbert good suggestion, care to elaborate how I can pick-up the co-ordinate? I am sure there is a PStricks or TikZ way to do it but I am not very familiar with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the package `zref-savepos` you can get the current coordinates. It needs at least two pdflatex runs. `\zrefy{<Label>}` is the current height from the bottom. With the other settings from the top you know what height you have to fill to get a full page tabular. Here is only an example on how it works. For demonstration I used only `\rule{0pt}{0.5\myHeight}`. You have to use the paper dimensions to get the correct `\myHeight`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\newlength\myHeight

\usepackage{amssymb}[2002/01/22] %% for the Box
\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
\newcounter{hcounter}
\setcounter{hcounter}{0}
\newcommand{\yesno}{\textsf{Yes}\hskip9pt\textsf{No} {\Large ~$\Box$}~~~~{\Large $\Box$}}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
\stepcounter{qnumber}%
\hfill\thehcounter.\theqnumber\hfill\hfill &\textsf{#1} &{\small\yesno}&    {\small\yesno}&{\small\yesno}\\ \hline%
}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{%
\stepcounter{hcounter}%  
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}%
\hfill\textbf{\thehcounter.0}\hfill\hfill&\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\bf\textsf{#1}}\\ \hline %
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{7mm}|p{8.61cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.55cm}|}
\zposy{TOP}\heading{Controls}
  \question{Control valves/actuators properly installed.}
  \question{Control valves/actuators operable.}
  \question{BMS signals operable.}
  \question{Control valves/actuators properly installed.}
  \question{Vibration isolation devices installed?}
\heading{Other} 
  \question{Access doors are operable and sealed? } 
  \question{Casing undamaged?}
  \question{Insulation undamaged?}
  \question{Condensate drainage is unobstructed?}
%% the end portion of the environment
%% add the remarks columns and close the longtable
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\bf {\textsf{DISCREPANCIES}}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{%
  \zsavepos{POS}\setlength\myHeight{\zposy{POS}sp}
\rule{0pt}{0.5\myHeight}    \the\myHeight    }\\\hline%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I marked your inline code with backticks. Have a look at your first version; there the `<Label>` didn't show up (got eaten as an unknown html entity).

Comment: ah thanks, maybe that I'll learn it in this year ... :-)

Comment: One more thing to learn: If you use "@Hendrik" somewhere in your comment, and there is already a comment that I wrote (as is the case here), then I get a notification of what you wrote. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Thanks it worked after some minor modification. Great code thanks.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Can we know those minor modifications? :-)

Comment: @azetina Can't really remember now. Wow is almost two years since. Pretty much this post of Herbert - who was new on the board then, introduced me to the wonderful world of Oberdiek's work.