# How do I generate a check-list?

Tags: lists, environments

Similar to the itemize or description environments I would like to have a check-list environment, with neat boxes on the right side, that I may check or uncheck. I guess I'm not the first having this idea, so I would be pleased if you could share your solutions.

**Edit:** Is there a way to make such a PDF interactive? So when viewing with a reader, the boxes might change from checked to unchecked and vice versa?

Comment: Related for checkboxes: [creating-boxed-check-mark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/creating-boxed-check-mark)

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/adding-vertical-stretch-at-a-table-row

Comment: I would use the [`listliketab`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listliketab) package.  Also, if you are creating checklists to boost productivity, looking for ways to generate pretty checklists is counterproductive. `:-D`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}     

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.2in}
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\-\oldmarginpar[\raggedleft #1]%
{\raggedright #1}}    

\newenvironment{checklist}{%
  \begin{list}{}{}% whatever you want the list to be
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand\item{\olditem -- \marginpar{$\Box$} }
  \newcommand\checkeditem{\olditem -- \marginpar{$\CheckedBox$} }
}{%
  \end{list}
}   

\begin{document}
\begin{checklist}
  \checkeditem   Open the \TeX book
  \checkeditem   Find the good page
  \item   Try to understand
\end{checklist}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Of course the checked/non-checked property could be implemented as an option but then it would be more difficult to stay compatible with packages that extend `\item` themselves. If you don't like the look of `\CheckedBox`, there are plenty of `\checkmark`s in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) so you can build your own checked box.

Comment: Yes, great, I just came back, as the checked/unchecked state was making me some headaches (as I've just finished a checkable item :D), thanks!

Comment: The code block just before the definition for the checklist env was causing me some trouble in combination with todonotes package, as the margins have been changed. For my document it was not necessary. BTW: neat example.

Comment: @math You can modify or suppress this part . Perhaps you can add an example with todonotes.

Comment: Nesting of checklists does not work for me. pfdlatex hangs and has to be aborted. Generating simple checklists works fine though.

Answer (score 3):

> Please see the [*Wikibooks* article on customizing itemised lists](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Customizing_Itemised_Lists).

You can use a regular `\itemize` environment, where 
“[…] you simply change the labels. It can be done manually for each entry with `\item[new symbol]`, eg `\item[$\star$]`.”

Or, you can change it globally with `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\star$}`, where `\labelitemi, \labelitemii, \labelitemiii, \labelitemiv` describe the labels for the list depth levels.

In your case, you could use the `\square` symbol from the `amsmath` package.

> For more information, please confer the *Wikibooks* article.

Comment: OP wants the boxes on the right side.

Comment: As I want to have many check-lists, I would repeat my self often to put explicitly the Box symbol in each item. I also discovered `\square` symbol from amsmath, but as amsmath has many symbols which I might not need at all, I tend to use latexsymbol, hoping its way less to include.

Answer (score 2):

So far I've copied [an answer](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2005-08/msg01644.html) from comp.text.tex which put boxes on the left side:

```
\usepackage{latexsym} % for squares for the check-list environment
...
\newenvironment{checklist}{%
  \begin{list}{}{}% whatever you want the list to be
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand\item{\olditem[$\Box$] }
}{%
  \end{list}
}
...
\begin{checklist}
   \item Bla...
\end{checklist}
```

However I'm a bit unsure if its right to put the boxes on the left side. Of course its then easy to follow which tasks are done, and which are left open, on the other side I'm used to check boxes on the right...

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an extremely simple, non-interactive checklist just to print. Here's what I came up with.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{changepage}
\linespread{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l } 
\qed &   \\ 
\qed &   \\ 
\qed &   
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```